# Deserialization in Java OOP

Tags: java, oop, deserialization

(the language is Java)

I'm having a problem here. I tried searching, but haven't found anything (maybe my search parameters weren't right, I don't know).
So let's say I have a person.txt file which is:

Joe; Germany; 25; joe@hotmail.com

I have a class such as the following one:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String age;
    private String email;    

    public Person(String name, String country, String age, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;         
    }

   (getters and setters)

}
```

I want to deserialize the person.txt file in order to have an instance of Person, but no matter how hard I tried, I'm not sure how I can do it. I'm aware that somewhere along the way I'd have to use a split(";"), but I'm having problems with this.

Comment: This is a college assignment and I read it wrongly. I thought we were supposed to read .lft files, or .ser files

Apparently, that is not the case, as a simple .txt file can be used, ergo I can use any of the solutions you propose (which I had already done in the last semester) along with a while loop.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deserialize a java object, you need to have a `no-argument` constructor defined in the class. So your `Person` class would look like this,

```
public class Person implements Serializable
{
    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String age;
    private String email;

    public Person( String name, String country, String age, String email )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
    }

    // no-args constructor
    public Person()
    {
    }

    // standard getters and setters goes here 
}
```

Other that that, Serialization and Deserialization is pretty straight-forward.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    Person p = new Person( "Test", "Au", "38", "test@gmail.com" );
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream( new File( "Serialize.ser" ) ); // This can be any name . For ex : person.txt
    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream( f );

    // Write object to file
    o.writeObject( p );
    o.flush();
    o.close();
    f.flush();
    f.close();

    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream( new File( "Serialize.ser" ) );
    ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream( fi );

    // Read objects
    Person personInput = ( Person ) oi.readObject();
    System.out.println( personInput.toString() );
    oi.close();
    fi.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple file handling too to extract the data in an array of objects of class person and then later use it however you require. An example code to understand the same is as follows:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String age;
    private String email;    

    public Person(String name, String country, String age, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;         
    }

    public person(){}

}

public class ReadLineByLine  
{  
    public static void main(String args[])  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("person.txt");       
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(fis);   
            String tempLineData = "";
            String[] elements;
            ArrayList <Person> People = new ArrayList<Person>();
            while(sc.hasNextLine())  
            {  
                tempLineData=sc.nextLine();        
                elements = tempLineData.split(";");
                Person p = new Person( (elements[0].trim()),  (elements[1].trim()),  (elements[2].trim()),  (elements[3].trim()) );
                People.add(p);
            }  
            sc.close();     
        }  
        catch(IOException e)  
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}
```